# Tornado Websocket Interaction with separate thread/application

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am trying to interact or send messages to clients on tornado from a separate server thread. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some code

```
waiters = set()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     print ("[HTTP](MainHandler) User Connected.")
     self.render("index.html")


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    cache = []
    cache_size = 200
    
    def open(self):
        global waiters
        print(list(waiters))
        print ('[WS] Connection was opened.')
        waiters.add(self)
        print(list(waiters))

    def on_message(self, message):
        print ('[WS] Incoming message:'), message
        if message == "toggle":
            global waiters
            for client in self.waiters:
                print("fired")
    def on_close(self):
        global waiters
        print(list(waiters))
        print ('[WS] Connection was closed.')
        waiters.remove(self)
        print(list(waiters))

     @classmethod
     def client_message_from_program(cls, JSONmsg):
         print("JSONmsg") #This does not print using add_callback
         print(JSONmsg)
         for client in cls.waiters:
             print('sent to client')
             client.write_message(json.dumps(JSONmsg))
```

Separate thread's code, hoping to interact/interface with WSHandler
LoopDeclaration is referencing the correct tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

```
    msg_json={"type":"StatusUpdate","message":"Connected","message1":"123412","Message2":"Calculating RSSI","Message3":""}
    LoopDeclaration.add_callback(WSHandler.client_message_from_program, msg_json)
```

This does not cause an exception, but it does not cause any further action from the WSHandler. No messages are passed.

Creating global list of clients and sending message that way will not work, or has not for me in testing. (global list would not update outside of WSHandler, sending messages outside of WSHandler unsupported in tornado 5.0 and beyond)

Any support would be appreciated. Some legacy threads mention starting my web-application as a 'special client' on the tornado WS would be the best method, but I have no idea how to accomplish that and have been unable to find a path forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Other stackoverflow suggested creating a 'special client' but had minimal info on technical accomplishments of this. I'm adding my solution here to aid others if they encounter the same problem.

Relevant Server Code:

```
class ApplicationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        server = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        data = {"type":"StatusUpdate","message":"Connected - Backend Application Ready","message1":"Current Action: Starting Up ","message2":" ","message3":" "}
        server.add_callback(WSHandler.send_message, data)
        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish()

    def post(self):
        datatype = self.get_argument('type', '')
        if datatype:
            server = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
            server.add_callback(WSHandler.send_message, self.request.body)

[Under WSHandler]
    @classmethod
    def send_message(self, message):
        if isinstance(message, bytes):
            x = urllib.parse.parse_qs(bytes.decode(message))
            message = x
        else:
            pass
        for client in waiters:
            client.write_message(message)
        #for session_id, session in self.session.server._sessions._items.iteritems():
        return True


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/', MainHandler),
  (r"/application/", ApplicationHandler),
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
  ], **settings)
```

Application/Special Client

```
    http_client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()
        response = http_client.fetch("http://localhost:8001/application/")
        print(response.body)
    except tornado.httpclient.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))
    post_data = {"type":"StatusUpdate","message":"Connected","message1":"Secondary Update from client","message2":"Calculating","message3":" "}
    post_data_encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data) #Make it into a post request
    http_client.fetch("http://localhost:8001/application/", method='POST', headers=None, body=post_data_encoded) #Send it off!
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, if anyone has advice for future please add them. I'm interested in the PUB/SUB model but didn't have time to adequately learn...